# Python: when multiple columns have the same value, replace the last one with null

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

my data looks like this:

| Text | Topic1 | Sentiment1 | Topic2 | Sentiment2 | Topic3 | Sentiment3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example1 | food | positive | food | negative | travel | positive |
| Example2 | animals | positive | animals | positive |  |  |
| Example3 |  |  | travel | negative | travel | negative |
| Example4 |  |  |  |  | food | positive |

I want to make sure that the same topic-sentiment combination cannot occur more than once for a given text. So the same topic can only occur more than once if the sentiment is different. If topic and sentiment is the same, the last topic-sentiment combination should be null. In the example above, this is my desired result:

| Text | Topic1 | Sentiment1 | Topic2 | Sentiment2 | Topic3 | Sentiment3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example1 | food | positive | food | negative | travel | positive |
| Example2 | animals | positive |  |  |  |  |
| Example3 |  |  | travel | negative |  |  |
| Example4 |  |  |  |  | food | positive |

How can I do this in Python?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are many libraries in python to process tabular data. You may give some preference here so that others can help you better. For example if you or your team are using any libraries now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Pandas, and have text, topic, and sentiment as columns.  Then drop duplicates to keep only the unique combinations.  If you want to report out by text in the end and put all of the entries in one row, you can groupby text and report out all of the columns and call them topic1, topic2, etc.

```
row1list = ['text1', 'food', 'positive']
row2list = ['text1', 'food', 'positive']
row3list = ['text2', 'python', 'positive']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['Text', 'Topic', 'Sentiment'])

df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
#     Text   Topic Sentiment
# 0  text1    food  positive
# 2  text2  python  positive
```